# Nativescript Vue ListPicker does not update it's items

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to load topics (just string values) from a backend and display them in the ListPicker. However the ListPicker won't update it's items which should be displayed.

The code is as follows:

```js
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Create Challenge" icon="">
            <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" @tap="goBack" />
        </ActionBar>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="TOPIC" class="fab lblSubTitle"/>
            <ListPicker :items="topics" v-model="selectedItem" />
            <Button text="check" @tap="checkIt" />
        </StackLayout>

    </Page>
</template>

<script>

    import {ObservableArray} from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array';
    import {FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase-service';

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                selectedItem: 0,
                topics: new ObservableArray(["some", "hardcoded", "items"])
            };
        },
        methods: {
            goBack() {
                this.$navigateBack();
            },
            checkIt() {
                this.topics.push("new item");
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log("Create Challenge - Loading Topics")

            // Fetch additional items from the Firebase DB
            FirebaseService.fetchTopics().then(result => {
                result.forEach(topic => {
                    this.topics.push(topic);
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>


<style scoped>
    .lblSubTitle {
        font-size: 15;
        margin: 10dp;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

So the FirebaseService.fetchTopics() returns an array of strings. This works perfektly fine and adds the received values to the ObserveableArray **topics**.
However the ListPicker only shows the hardcoded values. Not the dynamically added ones. Also the **checkIt()** method won't update the view.

I have tried to change **topics** to a conventional array with no effect.

[Link to the Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=EaZD46)

NativeScript Version: 6.5.0
Android Device: Pixel 2 - Android 9

Comment: ListPicker doesn't respond to changes on ObservableArray, try using a simple array and mutate it

Comment: @Manoj I have already tried it with a simple array with no success (same result) :(

Comment: Please share a Playground sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: [Link to the Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=EaZD46)

Comment: maybe try it in mounted instead of created?

Comment: Tried it. Using mounted  or created doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListPicker doesn't listen to changes on ObservableArray. You must use a simple Array and mutate the changes

```
this.topics = [...this.topics, "new item"];
```